# Software to easily edit Image File Execution Options in the registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I've done the replacement with Notepad with this option http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/notepad2-Replacement.html .

It work's very well. I'm just asking if there's a tool or app out there which eases the task.